# ScriptResource.axd throws 404 server error

Tags: asp.net

Iam running the application locally, performing the WebTest(UI)..I record the test, and stop recording, the test is running in the visual studio,

It thorws error telling "ScriptResource.axd throws 404  server error"

Excetly the error was Server '/' application not found.The scriptResource.axd not found.

Can anybody help me in resolving this problem.

Regards,
Gayathiri Venkatraman.

Comment: Not sure... Seems like it is either offtopic or belongs on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the HttpModule registered in your web.config?

```
<httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD"
           path="ScriptResource.axd"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```